# What could be the data structure used for start button on windows operating system

Tags: data-structures

What could be the data structure used for start button on windows operating system. When we click on start some items pop up so what could be data structure used inline to design this.

Comment: A simple list of objects that contain the display name and the action to perform would work just fine. This seems an odd question. What is it that you really want to know?

Answer (score 0):

I think LinkedList can be used as it is a list of all programs in start button.